# Ratio problem under given conditions

Tags: ratio

> The ratio of male to female pupils going on a skiing trip is 5:3. 4
>   male teachers and 9 female teachers are going on the trip. The ratio
>   of people going on the trip, including teachers is 4:3. How many
>   female pupils are going on the trip?

I understand to the point of getting m:f = $\frac{5}{3}$ and (m+4):(f+9) = $\frac{4}{3}$ and 3 x m =3m but I don't know how they got 5f and the rest of this equation - 3m = 5f and 3m + 12 = 4f+36 and 3m-4f = 24. Please can someone break it down and explain it if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{m}{f}=\frac 35$$
You can multiply both sides by $5f$
$$\frac{m5f}f=\frac{3(5f)}{5}$$
or $5m=3f$

The shortcut is if you have an equation $$\frac ab=\frac cd$$ you can write it as $$ad=bc$$

Comment: Thank you, that's really helped :)